# Finding from non-sequential columns

Tags: vba, find

I am a novice and trying to figure out an elegant strategy with VBA to find data from multiple, non-sequential columns with column specific criteria.

Example: Find rows where the three column specific criteria are all a match (logical And):
Column A, criteria 1; Column D:, criteria 2, Column F: criteria 3.

For sake of example let's assume Column A = Factory, Column D = Product, Column F = Location.

This is pretty simple on sheet, but on VBA I am puzzled with .find, application union and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Generally to use multiple criteria matching it is easier to use a loop like this :

```
DB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DB").Range("Db_Val").Value2
Dim A()
ReDim A(1, 0)

For i = LBound(DB, 1) To UBound(DB, 1)

    If Factory <> DB(i, 1) Then
    Else
        If Product <> DB(i, 4) Then
        Else
            If Location <> DB(i, 6) Then
            Else
                A(0, UBound(A, 2)) = i
                A(1, UBound(A, 2)) = DB(i, 2)
                ReDim Preserve A(UBound(A, 1), UBound(A, 2) + 1)
            End If
        End If
    End If

Next i

If UBound(A, 2) > 0 Then ReDim Preserve A(UBound(A, 1), UBound(A, 2) - 1)
```

Comment: Thank you R3uK. I see the simpleness of this piece of code blows me away and it is rather elegant I have to say. this said I have some study and adaptation to substitute what I had going on with .find based code.